# Trying to make a Gorilla Tag movement system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual-reality

I am trying to make a gorilla tag movement system but I have an error:

```
GetDrag does not exist in the current context
```

with my code saying just a simple "float GetDrag()".

I am watching this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5D2bN7xL5us&t=1s

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code. The error implies that the GetDrag method isn't accessible from where you're trying to call it. This could be for a number of reasons, e.g. it could be a private method that you're trying to call from outside the class that declares it. Code which shows the relationship between where the method is declared and where you're trying to call it from is essential to being able to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Gorilla tag's creator has open sourced the movement code under the MIT license

https://github.com/Another-Axiom/GorillaLocomotion

Answer (score 0):

make this

```
float GetDrag()
     {
         Vector3 handVelocity = (target.localPosition - 
         _previousPosition) / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
         float drag = 1 / handVelocity.magnitude + 0.01f;
         drag = drag > 1 ? 1 : drag;
         drag = drag < 0.03f ? 0.03f : drag;
         _previousPosition = transform.position;
         return drag;
     }
```